# struts2 tag ? directory and file path tag

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts2

is there any Struts2 tag that lets you choose the path of a folder ?
any solutions with jquery or html or jsp ?
I need a solution like that, client have to choose path of folder from Hard disk

```
<s:folder name="xmlFolder" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the current directory path  or folder here is the jsp code

```
 <%
String folder= request.getRealPath("");
  %>
```

otherwise use the `<input type="file" id="fileBrowser" onchange="test()"/>` which allows you to choose file dynamically

you must select an actual file, or the dialog box won't go away.
you can however, select a file within the desired folder, and then use a simple script to chop off the file part of the path.

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
  {
     var filePath=document.getElementById("fileBrowser").value;
var index=filePath.lastIndexOf("\\");
alert(filePath.substring(0,index));
    }
    </script>
```

suppose if you choose a file from the following path D:/test/file.txt and you need the folder name of the file "D:/test" is the thing your looking for then see the following link http://pastebin.com/Kncak3sr. i have pasted the code over there.

Comment: with <input type="file"/> I have just name of file, but me I need full path of folder, so user click in button and he choose a folder, and we get a full path of this folder

Comment: with <input type="file" id="fileBrowser"/>, we can just choose a file, but not a folder, always the same problem

Comment: I have always the same problem, dont forget that Im working with struts2